# Maven lifecycle mapping

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, jboss-developer-studio

I have parent [project] pom which have the

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    ....
</plugin>
```

In subproject [childpom], I am getting this error on the first line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

> Incompatible lifecycle mapping plugin version 1.4.0
>   jump to definition in parent pom.

Further env details:

- IDE : Jboss jeveloper studio v9.0.0
- JDK : java 8 64 bit.
- MAVEN : apache-maven-3.3.3

I am new to maven, pls suggest me where I went wrong?

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml files completely?

Comment: Why do you have lifecycle-mapping as a plugin configured in your pom?

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

different eclipse depends different lots of locale jar files.  so try use the relation version of the eclipse version.
you can find the version number from the installation folder. they should in features or plugins.
maybe is 1.6.2. you can try!